# How to link these two tables with the entity relationship model?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

If I have two entities, "Courses" and "Course_offerings", and they both have a key called "course number" , how do I relate these two entities? A relationship table does not make sense because it would be mapping the same course number to the same course number, which is redundant. But leaving them unlinked seems wrong. What is the correct way to do this for the ER model?

What would an ER diagram for this look like?

Comment: I don't know, since you don't say, but it sounds like Course Number is a candidate key of the `COURSES` table.  Similarly, I'm guessing that course number is a foreign key in `COURSE_OFFERINGS` so the tables are already related in a 1:M (one-to-many) relationship.  You can formalize this by declaring a foreign key constraint.

Comment: i don't quite understand your point ! can you describe your 2 tables ? maybe then it will make sense